# Flutter: Seralize ObjectBox objects as fields of other ObjectBox objects

Tags: flutter, objectbox

consider the following ObjectBox classes:

```html
@Entity()
class TestModel1 {
  @Id()
  int id;
  final TestModel2 testModel2; // un-seralizable

  TestModel1({this.id = 0, required this.testModel2,});
}



@Entity()
class TestModel2 {
  @Id()
  int id;
  final String test1;
  final int test2;

  TestModel1({this.id = 0, required this.test1, required this.test2});
}
```

**My goal** is to seralize `TestModel2` inside another ObjectBox object (or any other custom class inside ObjectBox)

**The Error I'm getting:** `Cannot use the default constructor of 'TestModel1': don't know how to initialize param testModel2 - no such property.`

**My question** is whether there's an annotation I can use to allow me to seralize special types, or is converting to and from json is the only option?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the field a `String` and serialize to JSON as you said.

Or, probably the better solution is to make the field a `ToOne<TestModel2>` relation.

https://docs.objectbox.io/relations